# How to create for each date between a date range a line MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, common-table-expression

Currently I have a table with dateranges, but I want a view in which I have for each date a line. How can I do this?

Before:

[image]

After:

```
-------+------------+----------+--------------
type   | date       | halfaday | fs_user
-------+------------+----------+--------------
Ferien | 2017-11-25 | 0        | 0
Ferien | 2017-11-26 | 0        | 0
Ferien | 2017-11-27 | 0        | 0
Ferien | 2017-11-28 | 0        | 0
Ferien | 2017-11-29 | 0        | 0
-------+------------+----------+--------------
```

Comment: Welcome to `StackOverflow[SO]`, the first thing to understand is that we are not a code writing service. So please be a bit more specific when asking question: *What have you tried so far with code example?* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"

Comment: I tried a couple things with CTE, but I have no clue how to do it.

Comment: Than write a short note about the couple of things in your question ;)

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Comment: I have found a solution, but thanks for the help.